# Recursively remove directories inside folder on same level Linux

Tags: linux

My structure is as follows:

```
├── Proj 1
│   ├── .git
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   └── example.cpp
├── Proj 2
│   ├── .git
│   ├── root_folder
│   └── README.md
├── Proj 3
│   ├── .git
│   ├── root_folder
│   └── README.md

...
```

Why is it when I do a `rm -ri \.git` it says:

```
rm: cannot remove `.git': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
rm -ri */.git
```

(not sure that's what you want)

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of `rm`'s recursive search are not right for finding and deleting directories below the current one.  The `-ri` flag will probably show each file beneath the `.git` folder right?

Happily if you are using `bash`, a one-liner with `find` will do what you need:

```
find . -name .git -type d -exec bash -c 'read -p "$0: Delete? " -n 1 -r && echo "" &&  case $REPLY in y) rm -rf "$0" ;; esac' {} \; -prune
```